# git rebase really old commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am trying to undo a really old commit that has already been pushed to the remote.
I looked around and thought that `git rebase` was probably the best solution.
so I ran the code:

```
git rebase -i <commit-id>
```

then edited:

```
pick <commit-id> <commit-title>
drop <commit-id> <commit-title>   <- the commit I want to delete
pick <commit-id> <commit-title>
```

Then tried applying this with `:wq`. This however triggered a LOT of merge conflicts (the commit is about half a year old).
The reason I want to undo the commit is because I accidentally added a file with credentials on it that I should not share with other collaborators.
So the only thing I want to undo is the "creation" of the file on the remote.
Is `git rebase` the best approach?
if so is there a way not to trigger all the merge conflicts (merge them just like before)?
I would rather not accidentally merge a conflict in the wrong way.

Also the commit I am trying to delete should not cause any conflicts with future commits. I tried running `git rebase` without dropping the commit but the merge conflicts still popped up.

Comment: What you need is `git filter-branch` or other 3rd party tools to remove the file from the entire history. This should help https://docs.github.com/cn/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository.

Comment: What does the commit do? Does it only add the unwanted file, or does it have other changes as well? If the latter, then you do not want to drop the commit, but edit it such that it does no longer add the unwanted file.

Comment: @j6t It also adds a line to the .env that points to the credentials file, but that's about it

Comment: I know there's an option called `--rebase-merges` (and other merge options) in the man page. But I never got to use it myself. Not sure how well that works. Did you try adding this one to your rebase command? EDIT: Nevermind. It says `Any resolved merge conflicts or manual amendments in these merge commits will have to be resolved/re-applied manually.` :( I guess you could do that each time using `git checkout REBASE_HEAD -- <conflict files>`, but that's still a hassle

Comment: Be sure to change the credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @ElpieKay!
`git filter-repo` managed to do its job
For full details look [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository). 
I first tried to use `BFG`, but I had some issues so I moved on to `git filter-repo`.

1. I made sure I had pushed all local commits.
2. I installed `git filter-repo`

```
brew install git-filter-repo
```

3. I cloned a new local repository (`git clone`).
   This step was because `git-filter-repo` alerted to run the command in a freshly cloned repo.
4. Delete the credentials file and add it to `.gitignore`.
   Make sure to save the credentials elsewhere if you haven't already.

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA
echo "YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA" >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "deleted file <file-name> and added to .gitignore"
```

5. newly cloned repo will not have an origin. Add it.

```
git remote add origin <your-repo-clone-url>
```

6. force push to origin

```
git push origin --force --all
```

7. Lastly ask to run a rebase on all other old branches in other local repositories.

```
git checkout <the-branch-cut-from-the-old-main>
git rebase origin main
```

And that should do the trick! Good Luck!